# Адекватный редирект в Joomla

Tags: seo, редирект, joomla, http-status-code-404, плагин

Добрый день.
Кто-нибудь использовал редирект в Joomla 3.0? На моём [блоге](http://seo-love.ru) уже устал бороться с редиректами с одной страницы на другую. Как я понял, стандартный плагин, что там используется, только для 404 ошибки. Никто не пробовал в коде модернизировать?

Comment: @Sector911, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д. Сейчас это похоже на саморекламу, которая в скоре будет удалена.

Comment: @Sector911 скажите какой вам нужен редирект если 301 я вам могу написать ответ если вам нужно сделать 404 страницу с меню навигации то тоже могу написать скажите точно!